# does second harmonic generation (SHG) take place in amorphous materials or disordered molecular assembly?

Tags: biophysics

[A review paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nbt894#abstract) claims that SHG can take place in biological samples, that is when the endogenous molecules assemble themselves reasonably in order, such as collagen fibril in connective tissues. I wonder if there is a reason why a degree of order is necessary for SHG to take place, besides the requirement of non-centrosymmetry.

Answer (score 0):

A degree of order is required so that the polarisation elements (the spatially localised sources for the SHG) can coherently add to form a propagating wave.